# Sending Statistics with Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, web

I would like to write a function to send some collected information from my web application as statistics, what I need is

> Sending information to the server without waiting for a feedback

I was told you use **HEAD** request to ignore the request body, then how can I send the statistics (I don't want to send them in the url)

To summarise, my question is:

1. What is the best way to send statistics?
2. How to send data in a HEAD request without including them in the URL (GET)?

Any advice is very welcome.

#### Additionally I cannot use any library, all I should use is pure javascript

Comment: Make a "post" instead of a "get" might solve it for you? .. "post" don't have its data in the url

Comment: thanks @PellePenna, yes I can do that, but this is not my question, I wanted to know what is the best way or how to send data inside a HEAD request

Comment: You can use the XMLHttpRequest's `setRequestHeader()` property, though as Quentin said, don't.

Comment: HEAD simply isn't an appropriate HTTP verb to use for this. You are giving the server new data so you should use POST (or PUT, but POST is almost certainly the right choice).

Comment: @PellePenna I guess Quentin answer my 2nd question

Comment: @Quentin thanks, I'll be waiting to see if any one suggest a better way to send statistics than using POST requests

Comment: He answered both as I see it

Comment: Now Yes, he edited the question :)

Comment: This post will show you what the header is used for, and from that you should be able to evaluate if to use the header or not: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields

Comment: And for everyone who don't want to read that :) .. I would answer: If the "statistics" is relevant for the request itself and its content, use "header", if not, "post" it.